# ¿Hay una manera de enviar una variable a un método mediante href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

disculpen tengo un php que muestra los registros de una tabla y mediante 2 links hago la función de modificar el registro o bien eliminarlo mediante un a href a un php distinto donde le paso el id del usuario mediante POST:

```
$row[] = "<td><a href='modificar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."'><i class='fas fa-edit'></a></td>";
$row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='eliminar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>";
```

Lo que pasa es que he decidido hacer un modal para eliminarlo en el mismo php sin que me refiera a otro para que se vea mas estético, la cuestión es que no encuentro una manera que no sea por post para pasar la variable del id especifico y poder rellenar el modal con sus datos para una edición, lo que he realizado con el $row[] es lo siguiente:

```
$row[]= "<td><a href='?fac=id=".$aRow['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal'><i class='fas fa-edit'></a><td>
```

Pero realmente no se como tomar eso en un script para evaluar la consulta y traer los datos de mi base de datos.

Comment: Lo que buscas lo puedes conseguir facilmente con AJAX. Ajax te permite hacer llamadas post / get sin la necesidad de recargar la página. Con lo cual podrías obtener los datos desde la BD de la fila en especifico y llenar los datos del modal con los datos recibidos en AJAX.

Comment: @IbaiA. me puedes orientar de favor amigo?

Comment: Es un tema muy extenso y sin tener el desarrollo de tu proyecto delante es algo dificil poder orientarte. Te sugiero que busques información acerca de "AJAX + PHP + MYSQL".
Basicamente lo que necesitas es, cuando des click en el enlace que te abre el modal, que AJAX llame a un archivo PHP en el que tu obtienes los datos desde BD de ese ID, y con la respuesta, en ajax, editar los campos del modal.

Comment: @IbaiA. eso se escucha perfecto para mi caso, me pondré a leer a ver si consigo algo útil, muchas gracias. ¿Qué sugieres que ponga de mi código en este post?¿Como obtengo el ID de la persona? ¿La estructura del moda?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con bootstrap y jquery, usando el primer código para enviar el id a eliminar.php

```
$row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='eliminar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>";


<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ¿Desea eliminar este registro?
                </div>
                    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                
            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>
```